# Async calls to Access Database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am working on a c# application which is communicating with an Access DB.

Currently I am in the process of converting our db calls to async calls using the async / await feature of c#5.
After converting the database access functions to their async counterparts (i.e. DbConnection.Open -> DbConnection.OpenAsync, DbDataReader.ExecuteReader -> DbDataReader.ExecuteReaderAsync ...) and inserting await / async I ended up with a method like this:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<int, ProductStockData>> getStockAmountPerOrderIntervalAsync() {
        var orderedProductsAndQuantities = await getOrderedProductsAndQuantitiesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        string stockAmountPerOrderIntervalQuery = @"SELECT  {...}";

        using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) {
            await dbConnection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(stockAmountPerOrderIntervalQuery, dbConnection)) {
                DbDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                {...}

                return productsAndStockAmountsPerInterval;
            }
        }
    }
```

When debugging I discovered that the two async calls are always executed on the spot (and not async) blocking the calling thread (and therefor the WPF application).

This method is called from a chain of methods all marked with the async modifier and calling the next method like this:

```
await [method]().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

At the beginning of this chain is an event handler call from the ui thread which looks like this:

```
async void mDbManager_OnConnectionEstablished() {
   await updateStockData(); // starting the chain of await call leading up to the aforementioned method call
   updateMissingProductsString();
}
```

After finding no problem with the code itself I started looking into the DB connection.
I am using an Access DB file (.mdb) and my current connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="{...}"
```

I also tried this one:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="{...}"
```

I did some research but the only thing I could find was, that prior to .Net 4.5 you had to append "Asynchronous Processing=true" to the connection string to allow for async calls. But I am using .Net 4.5.1. And even if I append it, it's not working.

Does anybody know if there is anything else I have to do to enable async calls to the Access DB?

EDIT:
I also just tried this using a OdbcConnection with this connection string:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq={...}
```

having the same blocking effect on the async db calls...

Comment: Since updateStockData is the first in the async chain, it would be useful to see what that is doing.

Comment: Can you add some trace output to dump out the thread id before the call to updateStockData and within the method you think is the problem?  I want to make sure that the problem method isn't actually running on the UI thread...

Comment: updateStockData just calls another async method using await [method]().ConfigureAwait(false); and so forth until the method above is called. I have stripped all other calls.

Concerning the traces - I just put a Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()) 
before every await method call and I can confirm that they all run on the same thread (the ui thread - that's why it's blocking my WPF UI).

Comment: What this basically boils down to is that the first async call not implemented by me are the two (potentially) async db calls OpenAsync and ExecuteReaderAsync - at this point the await should return with a Task freeing up the ui thread - but non of these are executed async on a different thread. 

So my guess is that this has something to do with the database engine / driver - or am I missing something?

Comment: @Estrich: async does not result in an additional thread, if the operation is IO bound. Please see the excellent blog post by Stephen Cleary: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: Ok, maybe not a new thread but shouldn't the execution at least be suspended and picked up later? If I debug my code the two async db calls are always executed immeditalty (ExecuteReaderAsync is executing for about 2 seconds before it returns with the results from the database freezing the calling thread) What good is a method labeled "async" if it never suspends execution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove the ConfigureAwait(false) calls in order for your solution to get asynchronous. Otherwise there will be no marshalling and your UI thread is blocked.

Some off-topic recommendations:

1. Use SQL Server Express. It's much more scalable than Access.
2. Also I would recommend to migrate to Entity Framework, which has some nice async support nowadays. I would only use ADO .NET directly only if I have to fully control data access or leverage some feature which aren't supported yet (i.e. Oracle UDTs)

   Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input Fabe but I'm not sure I'm following you. I was under the impression that the ConfigureAwait(false) calls are signalling the task that the execution of the code after the await does not have to happen on the same thread that started the async operation. I just tried it and it doesn't change a thing. Sadly I'm also stuck with the Access DB so changing to something else is no option...

Comment: You are right concerning the ConfigureAwait(false), my mistake. After some digging I found this blog post by Stephen Cleary: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html.
Basically it's saying you have to do 2 things in order for your GUI not to block: Use ConfigureAwait(false) and use async all the way down, meaning even your GUI event handler must be async. Are they already async?

Comment: In other words: Is your chain of methods completely async all the way down from the UI handlers to the DB access?

Comment: If that is the case, you most likely have to configure your driver accordingly, since async does not open a thread, but instead leverages the asynchronous IO processing on driver level: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177636(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Yep it's async all the way down.

Comment: About the driver config: that's what I was thinking. As you can see from my edit I also tried to connect via odbc and tried to set the DisableAsync to 0 in the connection string as well as through the registry - but that didn't change anything. I am beginning to think that the fault is with the jet engine itself...

Comment: In order to verify your theory, I would recommend to set up an SQL Server Express database and apply the following setting: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/asynchronous-processing/. If it works, you know that you have to dig deeper into the Jet engine settings.

Comment: You can also try to use OleDb provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0". Please not that you have to install the provider manually upfront.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to unblock the UI thread you can force your blocking calls on to a new task like this:

```
private async void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(() => getStockAmountPerOrderIntervalAsync());
}
```

This allows you to keep the rest of your code as it is.

**SOURCE:**
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html